# mysql between query in dates

Tags: mysql

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$lastweekdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 days")); 
$querytopscoreofweek  = 
"SELECT * FROM fb_user WHERE  last_date".
" BETWEEN $lastweekdate AND $currentdate ORDER BY oldscore DESC LIMIT 0,10";
```

i have field name last_date in this format $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
i want to execute the above query i want it to return all the users of last week and mean between $lastweekdate  and $currentdate  and which has also old_score greater in descending order and only 10 users,BUT THE PROBLEM IS THAT IT IS NOT RETURNING ANY THING ANY HINT PLZ

Comment: this looks okay. Is `last_date` a date field? Are you 100% sure it contains accurate data?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM fb_user 
WHERE last_date BETWEEN curdate() AND curdate() - interval 6 day 
ORDER BY oldscore DESC LIMIT 10
```