# how to return all rows when given value lies between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

its easier selecting a row whose value is between given number. But I m having no luck to figure out this-

I have a table in which there are two fields `min_age` and `max_age`. How to return all rows when given value lies between `min_age and max_age`

P.S. I m still a newbie in sql, please forgive me if this sounds too silly.

Thanks

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714899/mysql-compare-between-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199684/mysql-between-query-in-dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl`
WHERE 35 BETWEEN `min_age` AND `max_age`;
```

That ought to do it. Of course, I used 35. You can use any other value instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BETWEEN` to get your desired result

```
 SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE <some value> BETWEEN `min_age` AND `max_age`;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do the opposite, (provide a single value and find all the rows where the min and max age values bracket the provided value), then try

```
Select * From table
Where @myValue Between min_age And max_age
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question this is my first thought:

```
select * from from YOUR_TABLE where VALUE > min_age AND VALUE < max_age
```

However, I think there maybe more to your question, if these is please elaborate.

You could also try to use the `BETWEEN` operator

```
   SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE LastName BETWEEN 'Hansen' AND 'Pettersen'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp